# Google's hreflang tags redirects alone or do I need to put a script to do this job?

Tags: javascript, html, lang

I put this tag on my index:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://en.example.com.br">
```

If a person from an English speaking country opens the main url (https://example.com.br), does Google automatically redirect or should I create a script that takes the person's location and redirects it to the corresponding page?

Comment: What do you mean by "Google automatically redirect"?

Comment: I don't believe any major browser automatically redirects based on that tag, it's purely there to provide extra information to crawlers.